# Deauthorize page tab notification

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page, facebook-apps

Does anyone know if the deauthorize callback works for page tab applications? I've set this in the developer settings and it doesn't seem to work.

The page in question never even gets touched. I have logging in place to see if the page is hit but nothing shows. Anyone else got this working?

Thanks

Comment: Provide more information, if you would like useful assistance.

Comment: Sorry I actually thought the question was pretty self-explanatory. For canvas apps you can specify a deauthorize url for when people remove your application to perform whatever tidy up you need to do. This doesn't work for page tab applications and wondered if people knew if it should work. So in essence you can't clean up any data you may have associated with a particular pages install of your app. I've since discovered the only way to do this is to use the graph api to see if the app in question is still installed to a particular page and perform a cleanup yourself

Answer (score 0):

Is the page being accessed? Check your log files to see if your callback has been hit.

Last time I inspected our process, the signed_request value was not passed, instead the callback was still receiving the value in $_REQUEST['fb_page_id'] instead. You should also see a signature value which you can use to validate the request using the pre signed_request methodology.